# Implicitly lazy gather/take not considered a "lazy" object

Tags: lazy-evaluation, raku

The [documentation for gather/take mentions](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/gather%20take)

> Binding to a scalar or sigilless container will also force laziness.

However,

```
my \result = gather { for 1..3 { take $_² } };
say result.is-lazy # OUTPUT: «False␤»
```

Same happens if you use a scalar, and binding using `:=` Is there some way to create implicitly lazy gather/take statements?

*Update*: It's actually lazy, only it does not respond to the is-lazy method in the expected way:

```
my $result := gather { for 1..3 { say "Hey"; take $_² } };
say $result[0] # OUTPUT: «Hey␤1␤»
```

So the question is "What are the conditions for is-lazy to consider things actually lazy?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is really that you cannot actually tell what's going on inside a `gather` block.  So that's why that `Seq` object tells you it is not lazy.

Perhaps it's more a matter of documentation: if `is-lazy` returns `True`, then you can be **sure** that the `Seq` (well, in fact its underlying `Iterator`) is not going to end by itself.  If `is-lazy` returns `False`, it basically means that we cannot be sure.

One could argue that in that case `is-lazy` should return the `Bool` type object, which will also be interpreted as being false (as all type objects are considered to be `False` in boolean context).  But that would at least give some indication that it is really undecided / undecidable.